# Extracting Specfic range of values within javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of values as shown below

```
var jsonData = 
[{date:'Jan 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'Feb 2004',volume:22088000},    
{date:'Mar 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'Apr 2004',volume:22088000},
{date:'May 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'Jun 2004',volume:22088000},
{date:'July 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'Aug 2004',volume:22088000},
{date:'Sept 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'October 2004',volume:22088000},
{date:'November 2004',volume:22088000},{date:'Dec 2004',volume:22088000}]
```

I have two Date Pickers (***To Date*** and ***From Date*** ) in which i will pass this date value, for example (Jan 2004 and November 2004)

and on submit button , i want to collect the volume Data  in between them

```
var volumeData = [];
// I don't know how to write a condition 
priceData.push([i, jsonData[i].volume]);
```

How can i do that ?

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 1):

why overcomplicate things:

```
var volumeData = [], l = jsonData.length;
while (l--) {
    var d = Date.parse(jsonData[l].date);
    if (d >= startdate && d <= endate) { 
        volumeData.push(jsonData[l].volume) 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put your dates into a standard *numeric* format, not a human readable one.

Use (for example) the `datejs` library to do the conversion, or just use `yyyymm` instead.

Once you've done that, the rest should be obvious.  Only convert back to human readable format at the last possible moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - Ignore this answer: use @herostwist's answer; it's much simpler :)

There are a few stages to this:

To make things easier, you need to sort the data so we can extract a subset. Unfortunately, doing a naive sort by date will order them alphabetically, so we need to convert the date labels into something useful - i.e. numerical. (Note, Date.parse

```
for(var i=0, len=jsonData.length; i<len; i++) {
  jsonData[i].date = Date.parse(jsonData[i].date);
}
```

Then we can sort the data array:

```
jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.date < b.date ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Then iterate through the array until you find the first instance of the lower bound:

```
var lower = Date.parse('Jan 2004'),
    lower_index = -1;

for(var i=0, len=jsonData.length; i<len; i++) {
  if(jsonData[i].date === lower) {
    lower_index = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

And the last instance of the upper bound:

```
var upper = Date.parse('November 2004'),
    upper_index = -1;

for(var i=0, len=jsonData.length; i<len; i++) {
  if(jsonData[i].date === upper) {
    upper_index = i;
  }
}
```

Then you can take a slice of the original data and construct your subset:

```
var data = jsonData.slice(lower, upper+1),
    volumeData = [];

for(var i=0, len=jsonData.length; i<len; i++) {
  volumeData.push([i, data[i].volume]);
}
```